# Latency in BigQuery Data Availability

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I am using streaming insert to load a single row at a time in a Big Query Table.
This is the code

```
def insertBigQueryTable( tableName:String , datasetName:String, rowContent :java.util.Map[String, Object]): Unit = {
    val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService
    try {
      val tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName)
      val response =bigquery.insertAll( InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId).addRow(rowContent).build())
      if (response.hasErrors()) {
        val errors: util.Set[Map.Entry[lang.Long, util.List[BigQueryError]]]=response.getInsertErrors.entrySet()
        while(errors.iterator().hasNext){
          val error=errors.iterator().next()
          println(s"error while loading in bigquery $error.getValue")
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      case e: BigQueryException =>e.printStackTrace
    }
  }
```

I am able to instantly query the data via the query console in big query.
Then I am loading the table via a spark job (in a different job) running in dataproc cluster.But the data is not available in the spark dataframe immediately.
This is what I am doing

```
  def biqQueryToDFDefault(tabName: String, spark: SparkSession):DataFrame =
      spark.read.format("bigquery").option("table",tabName).load()
```

I am trying to understand if this is expected ? or is there a different way that I should be handling it(like trying to load the single row via a spark job)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming data to a bigquery table takes a while to become available. You can `SELECT` the data immediately but it sits inside a stream buffer for a while until its ready to get used by queries like `UPDATE, DELETE ...`